# Laurent series and convergence

Tags: complex-analysis

"Assume that a complex function $f(z)$ is regular in a neighborhood of $z = 0$ and satises $$f(z)e^{f(z)}= z$$  Write the polynomial expansion of $f(z)$ at $z = 0$ and find its radius of convergence."

I think it using Laurent series. But I can not find what is $f(z)$ in term of $z$?
Should I need to find what is $f(z)$ or Have another way to solve it?

Thanks you very much.

Comment: $$f(z)=W(z)$$The product log/Lambert-W function.

Comment: by definition of "$f$ is regular (holomorphic) at $z=0$" you can write $f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c(k) z^k$ for $|z| < R$. from $f(0) e^{f(0)} = 0$ you know that $c_0 = 0$, and you get $f(z) e^{f(z)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(z)^{n}}{(n-1)!} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a(k) z^k$ with $a(k) = \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \sum_{u(1)+\ldots+u(n) = k} \prod_{l=1}^n c(u(l))$ where $ \sum_{u(1)+\ldots+u(n) = k}$ is a sum over all the partitions of $k$ as a sum of $n$ integers, where the order counts and $u(l) \ge 1$

Answer (score 0):

$f(z)$ is a branch of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). The Maclaurin series for the branch analytic at $0$ is rather nice:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \dfrac{n^{n-1}}{n!} z^n$$

which can be obtained using the Lagrange inversion formula.  The radius of convergence is $1/e$, either using the Ratio Test or because the closest singularity is the branch point at $-1/e$.

Comment: and for proving this, it involves proving the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a stab a radius of convergence.

$$
w e^w = z.
$$
But $w\mapsto w e^w$, viewed as a function of a real variable $w$, has a horizontal tangent at $w=-1,\  z = -e^{-1}$.  Therefore its inverse function has a singularity at $-e^{-1}$.  If that singularity is closer to $0$ than any other, then the distance between that and $0$ is the radius of convergence; thus that is $1/e$.

As for the series in powers of $z$, I'd start with [this exponential formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_formula) to find the series for $f(z)e^{f(z)}$ in terms of the series
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n
$$
(notice that we can start with $n=1$ rather than $n=0$).  We get
$$
f(z) e^{f(z)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n z^n.
$$
The formula gives us the mapping
$$
(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots) \mapsto (b_1,b_2,b_3,\ldots)
$$
and you need to think about how to invert that.  Notice that what is asked for is the **series**, not a closed-form expression.

Comment: why the $1 +$ constant ? it should be $0$  since $f(0) e^{f(0)} = 0$